# Heroku fails on precompiling assets once it reaches application.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I don't get any errors locally, but when I push to Heroku (I don't precompile locally) I get this:

```
...

I, [2014-03-13T23:06:50.444079 #3521]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/public/assets/jquery-2.0.3.min-85a805038cb99ffbfec3467f84cad4c0.map
       rake aborted!
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
       (in /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.14/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/sass_importer.rb:11:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-1.1.6/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:7:in `new'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-1.1.6/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:7:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-1.1.6/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:7:in `map'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-1.1.6/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:7:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
To git@heroku.com:dailydeed.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

In my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rake'
gem 'fancybox-rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.0.rc'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.1.6'
gem 'ffi', '= 1.9.0'
gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'debugger'
    gem 'populator'
    gem 'ffaker'
end

group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
group :assets do
    gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end
```

I'm not sure what else to show that will help. I'm using the Foundation framework and compass, and I have it configured so that Heroku does the precompiling of assets.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your application file has to be .css (and not .scss) as necessary for Rails asset manifests files.

Comment: Could we please see application.scss?

Comment: Try pre compile locally and fix it before running on heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Writing /tmp/build_61158595-7e19-4bb5-88f0-728f7ab59f3f/public/assets/jquery-2.0.3.min-85a805038cb99ffbfec3467f84cad4c0.map

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

I think your error is to do with your JS - are you calling JQuery again or something? What about any calls in your `application.js` -- are you calling a function with more than one argument?

Comment: Turns out there was an error elsewhere in a view. Another person put a statement like `<%= @user.fname + ' ' + @user.lname %>` which I thought should work anyways but when I separated it into two statements it worked.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems right now with many gems that depend on sprockets in some way.
This might be an issue with compass-rails [issue#144](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/144)
I am trying to send a pull request with a fix for new.

In the meantime you need to lock sprockets to 2.11 in your Gemfile.
Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem "sprockets", "2.11.0"
```

and run

```
bundle update sprockets
```